# YQL data posting issue

Tags: post, yql

I'm new to YQL so this is propably (hopefully) an easy question.

I am trying to post into this webpage https://portaluc.puc.cl/uPortal/Login username and password.

I followed this guide to solve the issue:
http://christianheilmann.com/2009/11/16/using-yql-to-read-html-from-a-document-that-requires-post-data/

however, when I post into the webpage I receive this response:

```
    {
     "execution-start-time": "101",
     "execution-stop-time": "1427",
     "execution-time": "1326",
     "http-status-code": "502",
     "http-status-message": "Tunnel Connection Failed",
     "proxy": "DEFAULT",
     "content": "https://portaluc.puc.cl/uPortal/Login"
    }
   ],
   "cache": [
    {
     "execution-start-time": "99",
     "execution-stop-time": "100",
     "execution-time": "1",
     "method": "GET",
     "type": "MEMCACHED",
     "content": "09fb3008bbf8ca09c3fba9693b20efae"
    },
    {
     "execution-start-time": "100",
     "execution-stop-time": "100",
     "execution-time": "0",
     "method": "GET",
     "type": "MEMCACHED",
     "content": "190.8.76.67"
    },
    {
     "execution-start-time": "102",
     "execution-stop-time": "103",
     "execution-time": "1",
     "method": "GET",
     "type": "MEMCACHED",
     "content": "https://portaluc.puc.cl/robots.txt"
    },
    {
     "execution-start-time": "1254",
     "execution-stop-time": "1254",
     "execution-time": "0",
     "method": "GET",
     "type": "MEMCACHED",
     "content": "https://portaluc.puc.cl/robots.txt"
    }
   ],
   "redirect": {
    "from": "https://portaluc.puc.cl/uPortal/Login",
    "status": "302",
    "content": "https://portaluc.puc.cl/uPortal/render.userLayoutRootNode.uP"
   },
   "javascript": {
    "execution-time": "1330",
    "instructions-used": "4000",
    "table-name": "htmlpost"
   },
   "user-time": "1430",
   "service-time": "1407",
   "build-version": "37740"
  },
  "results": {
   "postresult": null
  }
```

Thanks in advance for the help